# How to create relative symbolic link in mac OS?

Tags: macos, symlink

How to create a relative symbolic link that would always point to original folder two levels up? I would like to create a computer-independent alias that would work on any machine, provided that the original folder exists two levels up.

Basically, what I want is this:

```
  |-- Original    
  |-- folder 1    
    |-- folder 2
      |-- Original alias
```

I need this for my XCode project structure. I've tried:

```
ln -s Original /../../Original
```

but it creates an alias that cannot find its original folder.

Comment: Why not move this to [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think, you have the order of the arguments backwards. It should be:

```
$ ln -s <dest> <link>
```

Where `<dest>` becomes the contents of the new link created.

In your specific example:

```
$ cd "folder 1"/"folder 2"
$ ln -s ../../Original Original
```

Or, in one command, from base directory:

```
$ ln -s Original "folder 1/folder 2/Original"
```

Comment: also, note that you must enclose `"<dest>"` in quotes, because otherwise bash will auto-expand it to an absolute path, and you'll end up creating an absolute symlink, not a relative one

Comment: @AlJey The only way I can think of that `bash` would do that is if `<dest>` started with `~`. I've never seen it take something like `../../Original` and convert that into an absolute path.

Comment: @twalberg Well, on my system (10.11.6) this happens every time. This was, in fact, always the case for me even on older versions. Not only in OS X, but in Ubuntu as well. Bash generally tries to auto-expand paths, always.

Comment: @twalberg, Are you sure? It prints `link source_file target_file` for me.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Yes - just a difference in terminology. `<link>` in my answer, and `target_file` from the usage message are the thing that gets created, referencing `<dest>` or `source_file`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

take out the first `/` - thats an absolute link from root, you want `../../` to be relative from current location.

Comment: still, no luck. Finder cannot find original folder